# tcl formatting floating point with fixed precision

Tags: tcl

```
# the unit of period is picosecond
set period 625000.0

set period_sec [format %3.6g [expr $period * 1e-12]]
puts $period_sec
```

result:  6.25e-07

Is there a way to force tcl to get results like 625e-09

Comment: I want to have result either in e-09 or in e-12

Comment: A sort of engineering notation thing? Good question; can't think of anything neat offhand (and I'm about to lose internet for the rest of the day, so can't figure out anything more complex…)

Comment: What should happen if you have the result `6.25e-10`? Should it become in `e-09` or `e-12`? (basically, always round the exponent up or down, or the closest one?

Comment: Actually the both are acceptable for me, there is no difference, I want to get the results either in e-09 or e-12. (lets say always get e-09)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to format it to the nearest exponent, you could use a `proc` which formats it like this:

```
proc fix_sci {n} {

  # Not a sci-fmt number with negative exponent
  if {![string match "*e-*" $n]} {return $n}

  # The set of exponents
  set a 9
  set b 12

  # Grab the number (I called it 'front') and the exponent (called 'exp')
  regexp -- {(-?[0-9.]+)e-0*([0-9]+)} $n - front exp

  # Check which set of exponent is closer to the exponent of the number
  if {[expr {abs($exp-$a)}] < [expr {abs($exp-$b)}]} {

    # If it's the first, get the difference and adjust 'front'
    set dif [expr {$exp-$a}]
    set front [expr {$front/(10.0**$dif)}]
    set exp $a
  } else {

    # If it's the first, get the difference and adjust 'front'
    set dif [expr {$exp-$b}]
    set front [expr {$front/(10.0**$dif)}]
    set exp $b
  }

  # Return the formatted numbers, front in max 3 digits and exponent in 2 digits
  return [format %3ge-%.2d $front $exp]  
}
```

Note that your original code returns `6.25e-007` (3 digits in the exponent).

If you need to change the rule or rounding the exponent, you will have to change the `if` part (i.e. `[expr {abs($exp-$a)}] < [expr {abs($exp-$b)}]`). For example `$exp >= $a` could be used to format if the exponent is 9 or below.

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/AvB5JU) of above code for 'closest' exponent.

---

For Tcl versions before 8.5, use `pow(10.0,$dif)` instead of `10.0**$dif`

Comment: @TigranKhachikyan Awesome! Also, saw your other comment. You can simplify it to get only e-09/e-12 by using only one part of the `if` and picking the one you need (either `a` or `b`) if you need any one of the two.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is anything in the format command that will help you directly. However, if you consider a slight variation on the format code, then it may be a lot easier to get what you want (with a bit of string manipulation):

```
format %#3.6g $number
```

gives a number like: `6.25000e-007`

This can be parsed more easily:

- Extract the exponent
- Determine the number of positions to shift the decimal point
- Shift it and replace the exponent

It is not entirely straightforward, I am afraid, but it should be doable. Wiki page http://wiki.tcl.tk/5000 may give you some inspiration.